# Reactjs: props.location.state is undefined when routing with Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set up routing between two different websites (hosted locally on different ports right now) where after clicking on a button on the first site, the user is redirected to the second site and there is some data being passed. I have set this up using a react router Link. In my code, I have something like

```
<Link to={{ pathname: 'http://localhost:4000/register', state:{ consent:'true'} }} target='_top' >
<button>Click me</button>
</Link>
```

The link works correctly and redirects to `localhost:4000/register`, but when I try to access the state data with `this.props.location.state` in the `Register` component on the second website, I get that it is undefined. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong, or if there is a better way of doing this?

On the second website, in `App.js`, I have set up a route to the register component like so

```
<Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
```

Then, inside the `render()` method of the `Register` component, I'm trying to access `this.props.location.state` but it is undefined.

Thanks

Comment: Typically you push to a route defined in your `Router`, i.e. just path, not the entire URL with root/base URL. Is the `Register` component correctly rendered within a `Router` and correctly receiving [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props)? Can you provide that code in your question?

Comment: I think so. I'm trying to pass data between two different websites when the user clicks a link, so I have to enter the entire URL as otherwise it would only route to paths within the current application.

Comment: Assuming you're using `react-router-dom`, the `Link` component is intended to link to paths/routes within the same application, otherwise, use a regular `<a />`. I don't think you can transmit route state between two route context providers, i.e. two separate apps, other than via the URL string as query parameters. If the other app was more a server you could send a POST request with data in the request body.

Answer (score 0):

In `Link`, don't give full url in `pathname`, it will reload the browser and all your state etc is lost. Also, `target="_top"` will cause the page to reload.

Just provide path i.e. `/register`

```js
<Link to={{ pathname: '/register', state:{ consent:'true'} }} >
    <button>Click me</button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Yeah, but that redirects to localhost:3000/register. I want it to redirect to localhost:4000/register, which is a different website hosted on a different port. Is there another way I can send data to a different website without necessarily passing it in the query string?

Comment: i see - no it won't work like that... you can pass around state with-in the app(3000)..if you want to redirect to external url then query param is your friend.